# Preferred approach to safe arithmetic type conversions

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to avoid `Long.toInt()` and other conversion methods that will silently truncate the numeric value. In Java I'd normally use [`Math.toIntExact()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toIntExact-long-) or some other static method from a 3rd party library.

What would be the preferred way to implement this in Kotlin? I'm leaning towards defining extension function in the basic Kotlin number types e.g.:

```
fun Long.toIntExact(): Int {
    return Math.toIntExact(this)
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can just call `Math.toIntExact()` directly - what exactly are you trying to achieve? Declaring your own extension wrappers is also fine.

Comment: I'm new to Kotin and I'm trying to understand what is the right/preferred/idiomatic approach for this. Maybe the extension functions are discourage for types in stdlib? Maybe using Java `Math` is discouraged because it restricts Kotlin to running on JVM?

Comment: This also depends on the context: if you're building an app then I'd suggest just calling the `Math` method directly. Wrapping existing Java API with extension functions doesn't add much and you'll just have more code to maintain. If you're building a multiplatform library, then declaring an `expect` extension function and implementing it on JVM by delegating to `Math` is the way to go.